# How to enable network boot / change BIOS settings on all nodes of a cluster?

Tags: deployment, remote-access, bios

I've got a homogenous cluster of several dozen nodes, and I've got CMM modules controlling them.

I need to enable network boot on all these nodes, in order to redeploy them.

Is there a way to do this automatically, without manually logging onto each node via CMM console and changing the boot sequence?